# Minimize $x + z$ subject to $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $y^2+z^2 = 4$

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker, qclp

I'm trying to solve this problem by KKT's condition:

> $$\begin{align*}
> \text{min} & \quad x + z \\
> \text{s.t} & \quad x^2 + y^2 = 1 \\
>            & \quad y^2+z^2 = 4
> \end{align*}$$

One of the regularity conditions is **linear independence constraint constraint qualification** (LICQ), which is

> The gradients of the active inequality constraints and the gradients of the equality constraints are linearly independent at $x^{*}$.

Could you please verify if I correctly apply the KKT's theorem? Thank you so much for your help!

---

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Put $f(x,y,z) = x + z$, $h_1(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-1$, $h_2(x,y,z)=y^2 + z^2 -4$, and $\mathcal K= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid h_1(x,y,z) = h_2(x,y,z) = 0\}$.

Because $\mathcal K$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, the problem has a solution.

Moreover, $\nabla f (x,y,z) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $\nabla h_1 (x,y,z) = \begin{pmatrix} 2x \\ 2y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $\nabla h_2 (x,y,z) = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2y \\ 2z \\ \end{pmatrix}$.

Next, we check if **LICQ** is satisfied by considering the system of equations: $$\begin{cases}
 \mu_1 \nabla h_1 (x,y,z) + \mu_2 \nabla h_2 (x,y,z)=0 &=0 \\
  h_1(x,y,z) &= 0\\
  h_1(x,y,z) &=0
\end{cases}
\iff 
\begin{cases}
 \mu_1  \begin{pmatrix} 2x \\ 2y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \mu_2 \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2y \\ 2z \\ \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} \\
  x^2 + y^2 &= 1\\
  y^2+z^2   &= 4
\end{cases}$$

$$\iff \begin{cases}
x \mu_1 &= 0\\
y(\mu_1 + \mu_2) &= 0 \\
z \mu_2 &= 0 \\
x^2 + y^2 &= 1\\
y^2+z^2   &= 4
\end{cases}$$

If $\mu_1 \neq 0$ then $x=0$. It follows that $y^2 =1$ and $z^2 =3$. Hence $\mu_2=0$ and thus $y(\mu_1 + \mu_2) \neq 0$, which is impossible. If $\mu_2 \neq 0$ then $z=0$. It follows that $y^2 =4 >1$, which is impossible. As such, $\mu_1= \mu_2 =0$ and thus LICQ is satisfied. It follows from KKT's theorem that the solution satisfies

$$\begin{cases}
  h_1(x,y,z) &= 0\\
  h_1(x,y,z) &=0 \\
\nabla f (x,y,z) + \mu_{1} \nabla  h_1(x,y,z) + \mu_{2} \nabla  h_1(x,y,z)&=0
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
  x^2 + y^2 &= 1\\
  y^2+z^2   &= 4 \\
 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} +\mu_1  \begin{pmatrix} 2x \\ 2y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \mu_2 \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2y \\ 2z \\ \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}
\end{cases}$$
$$\iff
\begin{cases}
  x^2 + y^2 &= 1\\
  y^2+z^2   &= 4 \\
2 \mu_1 x &= -1\\
y(\mu_1 + \mu_2) &=0 \\
2 \mu_2 z  &= -1
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
  x^2 &= 1\\
  z^2   &= 4 \\
y &= 0\\
\end{cases}$$

Hence $(x,y,z) =(\pm1,0,\pm2)$. After comparing the values at these points, we get the solution is $(-1,0,-2)$.

Comment: Why KKT ? Lagrange multipliers is much simpler. You do not handle inequalities in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct, I just corrected a small typo in the notations of $f(x, y, z)$.